# Fails to find gsutil on windows with R cloudml package

Tags: r, google-cloud-ml, gsutil

I’m getting the following error when I try to submit a training job to Cloud ML using the cloudml package (I’m replicating the keras fraud example [here](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/blog/keras-fraud-autoencoder.html)):

```
Error in gsutil_binary() : failed to find 'gsutil' binary
```

I’ve used `gcloud_install()` and installed everything, and set up my configurations with the shell as it opens after install. Running `gsutil --version` gives me `gsutil version: 4.28`, so it seems to have installed OK.

Anything I’m missing?

Other info:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.6.3
```

Also asked [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/cloudml-package-error-in-gsutil-binary-failed-to-find-gsutil-binary/4950/4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved [here](https://github.com/rstudio/cloudml/issues/122) with issue 122 on the github repo. It was an error with the cloudml package.

Comment: Please accept your own answer if it really solved the issue, so that the community can identify that this question is solved.